# Why can't Python rich print text styles, only colors, on Windows command line?

Tags: python, windows, rich

The problem is that I can't print any text style.

This is my code, and I don't think it's faulty:

```
from rich.console import Console

console = Console(highlight=False)

console.print("Test print")
console.print("[green]Test print (green)")
console.print("[bold]Test print (bold)")
console.print("[bold underline]Test print (bold underline)")

input()
```

This is what I get after running the script:

[image: screenshot of terminal output]

And this is what I get when I run

```
python -m rich
```

in the cmd:

[image: screenshot of terminal output of "python -m rich"]

What should I do? I tried it on Windows Terminal (from MS Store), and I got much more color and all the text styles, but I can't set Windows Terminal as default (I have Windows 10, not Windows 11).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The classic Windows terminal doesn’t support any of the text styles, and only 16 colours.